# Problema com sessões no Tomcat

Tags: java, servidor, tomcat, servidor-de-aplicação

Gostaria de saber o seguinte pessoal, uma aplicação da empresa apresenta um numero elevado de sessões no `manager` do `Tomcat`.

O sistema vem subindo no numero de usuários e gostaria de saber dicas dos colegas de `forum` o que eu poderia fazer para ver o que tem feito com que o numero de sessões suba e trave o sistema, fazendo com que se de um stop e start no manager e depois faça um `shutdown` e `startup` via terminal.

A aplicação em Java foi desenvolvida usando `Java 7`, `JSF`, `Spring` para Injeção de dependência, `Hibernate` entre outros.

Obrigado

Comment: Qual é o tempo de timeout que você configurou no web.xml? O correto não é reiniciar o serviço quando há um problema. O correto é entender o que está gerando o resource leak. Recomendo que você use o VisualVM ou outra ferramenta de profile.

Comment: `<session-config>
        <session-timeout>30</session-timeout>
    </session-config>`

Comment: @LeonardoCosta essas ferramentas são gratuítas, como funcionam?

Obrigado

Comment: Sim, é. Ele está dentro do próprio JDK, no diretório bin tem o arquivo jvisualvm. Aqui tem um exemplo: http://mvweb.mv.com.br:8080/documentacao/anexos/html/guias/guia_configuracao_java_visualvm/index.html?utilizacao.html

Comment: Vi em um post em inglês que não é uma boa prática fazer o reinicio automático do servidor, melhor mesmo é tentar descobrir porque o servidor está caindo ou travando. http://serverfault.com/questions/506180/is-auto-restarting-services-like-tomcat-a-good-idea

Comment: Tomcat em produção costuma ser complicado. Existe algum empecilho em migrar pro jboss?

Comment: @WeslleyTavares o chefe pensa em migrar para o `WildFly` mas precisa adaptar o sistema por conta por exemplo do `Maven`

Comment: Essas alterações serão menos dolorosas do que postergar esse ato inevitável e ficar sofrendo com os memory leak do tomcat.

Comment: @WeslleyTavares essa migração sera em breve mas por enquanto tenho que lidar com essa atitude. Obrigado pela ajuda